# unknown mail going from my mail box , cant see while sending it

Tags: email, outlook, hacking

When I send mail from outlook an extra mail is being generated and send to an unknown id . Why does this happen and how can this be prevented.

Comment: Are you using your own Mail-Server or a hosted Mail-Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Outlook with Exchange, the exchange server keeps track of all incoming and outgoing mail. In addition, outlook should keep a copy of all sent email as well. Use one of those sources to obtain the email address the extra copy is being sent to. then you can use the Exchange Management Console to edit the settings on your mailbox and prevent outgoing mail to that address.

As an aside, this sounds very much like some sort of malware. Please run a scan against your system as soon as possible, and ensure that there is not other activity going on. If you have sent any sensitive information (accounts, passwords, *et cetera*), please change the passwords to all related accounts immediately.